# Remove div between div using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to remove `div` elements which are loaded dynamically between two static `div` elements.

**HTML**

```css
<div id="defaultFirst">
</div>
..
..
..
<div id="defaultLast">
</div>
```

There are some `div` elements which are loaded in between those two static `div` elements. Now I need to remove those before I append some other elements.

I tried using `$('#defaultFirst').nextAll('div').remove()` but that removed the `#defaultLast` element too.

I know that I can get the ids of the dynamic `div` and remove. But I need to know if there is any simpler way to remove those dynamic `div` elements?

Comment: try `$('#defaultFirst').nextAll('div').not("#defaultLast").remove()` or  `$('#defaultFirst').nextAll('div').not(".doNotRemoveClass").remove()` for more elements

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `nextUntil()` instead of `nextAll()` and pass in a selector which selects your `#defaultLast` element:

```
$('#defaultFirst').nextUntil('#defaultLast').remove();
```

> `.nextUntil( [selector ] [, filter ] )`
>
> Description: Get all following siblings of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object passed.
>
> — [jQuery's documentation on `nextUntil()`](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/)

If you have elements which aren't `div` elements between those two which you aren't wanting to remove, you can specifically remove only `div` elements by passing in a selector to your `remove()` call:

```
$('#defaultFirst').nextUntil('#defaultLast').remove('div');
```

Comment: Love the way you edited the answer. Provided more in depth info.

Comment: Here is a working example for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/r9pzfkge/

Comment: Thanks for the faster reply.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend getting to the cause of why the divs are appearing in the first place rather than hacking like this. However if you have to then the following should work

```
$('#defaultFirst').nextAll('div').not('#defaultLast').remove();
```

Codepen example - http://codepen.io/webknit/pen/ZeZXdQ

Comment: @webknit I didn't. He got one for the wrong post before and for the updated one its getting upvoted now.

Comment: Oki i will also upvote. By that you will be able to comment on further  questions on SO.